# fine uploader gallery template

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

Good afternoon
I am keen to explore the benefits of Fine Uploader. http://fineuploader.com/demos.html

Sadly I haven't got very far with the installation. As a novice learning JS I have some inherent weaknesses - so I thought I would start with getting the Fine Uploader 'gallery.html' template working.

So I have downloaded the plug in from GITHUB https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader , extracted all the zipped files and exported them under a folder located in my root. I then located gallery.html (which is buried in the path domain/fine-uploader-master/client/html/templates/gallery.html) and loaded it into my browser expecting to see the demo version of gallery.html work. But all I get is a blank page. Looking inside the gallery.html I have tried changing the paths to fine-uploader-gallery.css and added the file fine-uploader.js to the directory. Still no joy.

I know I am doing something really silly here. If anyone can help me just get this template file running from the downloaded folder (as above) of what looks like a great plug in I would be so grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Follow the getting started guide on the documentation site at http://docs.fineuploader.com. All of your questions will likely be answered there.

Comment: Hi Ray. I have seen your name widely used on the support boards. So I am guessing you are key to this wonderful looking plug-in's success. We have already done as you suggested but to be honest we couldn't understand the 'getting started' section. So that's why we thought we would start with what we hoped was an out-of-the-box ready to run (gallery.html) script --- hoping it would work like blueimps index.html does. We know how to work backwards from an out-of-the box script -  and we can see fine-uploader is much more functional. Does an out of the box php-server fine-uploader script exist?

Comment: "Does an out of the box php-server fine-uploader script exist?" Yes, and this is covered in [page 3 of the getting started guide](http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server.html). The getting started guide is aimed at beginners. If you follow the guide from page 1 to page 3, you will be able to get an uploader up and running.

Comment: In short, if you are using Fine Uploader UI for traditional (not S3 or Azure) endpoints, you need a template in your document, JavaScript to initialize Fine Uploader, an element to attach the Fine Uploader instance to, and a server to handle Fine Uploader's various requests. The getting started guide walks you through this, with the last page detailing how to get a ready-made PHP server using composer.

Comment: Honestly Ray. I am beginning to feel like the daftest guy alive. I have been here http://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server.html several times at least - and read a steps 1-5 - all on a single page. I cant find links to pages 2 and 3 - and I suspect that is the real problem!

Comment: That is page 3, that last page in the guide. Start from the first link on the docs homepage, or jump to any page you want.

Comment: I have been through 01-03 already and many other pages. So for example page 1 of getting started. Ive done the traditional download and the next thing I am told to do is var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({/* options go here ... */});

Comment: That line is where our understanding problem starts. We don't understand what to do with that line of code. Where do we put it? How do we configure the options. Its to big a jump to get straight into that for designers like us. What we do is take an out of the box script that just works with no config and then start to modify it from there. It would be brilliant if that was the case with the so much better fine uploader product.

Comment: I'd like to discuss this in more detail, but Stack Overflow isn't the proper venue. Can you delete this question, open up a new issue in the Fine Uploader issue tracker, and there we can discuss necessary improvements to the docs to allow designers such as yourself to adopt Fine Uploader?

Comment: Yes of course Ray. Thank you. Is there a link foe the issue tracker so I end up in the correct place? I will delete this afterwards. Thanks again

Comment: You can find the issue tracker in the GitHub repository at https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader.

Comment: Have done as requested and opened up a GitHub issue Ray. "Documentation-Getting Started for Dummies". Happy to delete this post now?